# Java - Exceptions ignored while processing on separate thread within annotation

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-aop, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have an annotation which allows us to consume Kafka messages using a Polled Consumer. It's designed for long-running jobs so that one thread is processing the message, while the other remains available for polling to prevent Kafka from thinking our service has failed and rebalancing the consumers.

We're using Spring AOP.

Class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around(value = "@annotation(pollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule,..)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
      PollableStreamListener pollableStreamListener, Object dataCapsule) {
    if (dataCapsule instanceof Message) {
      Message<?> message = (Message<?>) dataCapsule;
      AcknowledgmentCallback callback = StaticMessageHeaderAccessor
          .getAcknowledgmentCallback(message);
      callback.noAutoAck();

      if (!paused) {
        // The separate thread is not busy with a previous message, so process this message:
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
          try {
            paused = true;

            // Call method to process this Kafka message
            joinPoint.proceed();

            callback.acknowledge(Status.ACCEPT);
          } catch (Throwable e) {
            callback.acknowledge(Status.REJECT);
            throw new PollableStreamListenerException(e);
          } finally {
            paused = false;
          }
        };

        executor.submit(runnable);
      } else {
        // The separate thread is busy with a previous message, so re-queue this message for later:
        callback.acknowledge(Status.REQUEUE);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

We only want to process one message at a time, so the `paused` flag is used to decide whether the message should be processed now, or re-queued for later.

The `Runnable` is used to process the message (using `joinPoint.proceed()`), then acknowledge the message back to Kafka. This is done in a separate thread via the `executor`.

I've found that if an exception is thrown inside the `runnable` that it is caught inside the `catch` statement, but then is not propagated when we throw the new `PollableStreamListenerException` exception, meaning that the failure does not end up in the DLQ.

I believe this is because the execution is happening on another thread, and the main thread has moved on in its execution (not waiting the second thread to process the message), and is therefore no longer able to propagate to the DLQ. However, I might be mistaken with this since I'm not very familiar with how multi-threading works.

I've tried modifying the `executor.submit(runnable)` to `executor.submit(runnable).get()`, which solves the issue. However it results in blocking the execution of the main thread until the other thread has finished executing, which means that the main thread is no longer available to poll for new messages. In effect this makes our Kafka consumer no longer a pollable consumer, which defeats the whole purpose of having the annotation.

Does anyone know if it's achievable to have the main thread continuing to run and poll for messages, and at the same time to have exceptions thrown inside the `runnable` propagated to the DLQ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

To provide a bit more context, we use the annotation as follows:

```java
  @PollableStreamListener
  public void submitDeletion(Message<?> received) {
// Process message
}
```

The `submitDeletion` method is called whenever a new message is received on the Pollable message source. We check for new messages using a `@Schedule`:

```java
 @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${app.pollable-consumer.time-interval}")
  public void pollForDeletionRequest() {
    log.trace("Polling for new messages");
    cleanupInput.poll(cleanupSubmissionService::submitDeletion);
  }
```

---

**Update:** attempting to use CompletableFuture

As per the comment made by @kriegaex, I've attempted to use a `CompletableFuture`. I simplified my example so that it is more of a POC.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PollableStreamListenerAspect {

  private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

  private volatile boolean paused = false;

  @Around(value = "@annotation(pollableStreamListener) && args(dataCapsule,..)")
  public void receiveMessage(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
      PollableStreamListener pollableStreamListener, Object dataCapsule) {
    if (dataCapsule instanceof Message) {
      Message<?> message = (Message<?>) dataCapsule;
      AcknowledgmentCallback callback = StaticMessageHeaderAccessor
          .getAcknowledgmentCallback(message);
      callback.noAutoAck();

      if (!paused) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
          log.info("Start execution logging");
          try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error while sleeping", e);
          }
          log.info("End execution logging");
          throw new RuntimeException("Throwing exception to force handle statement");
        }, executor).handle((s, t) -> {
          log.info("Inside handle block:");

          if (t != null) {
            log.info(t.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
          }
          return null;
        });

        try {
          completableFuture.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Error while doing join()", e);
        }

        callback.acknowledge(Status.ACCEPT);
      } else {
        // The separate thread is busy with a previous message, so re-queue this message for later:
        callback.acknowledge(Status.REQUEUE);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I run the function inside the `CompletableFuture` using my `ExecutorService` instance. It throws an exception, which is handled inside the `.handle()` block.

My first test did not have the following lines of code, and I found that the function ran on another thread without blocking the main thread from polling, but the exception thrown inside of `handle()` was not propagated to the DLQ. Lines of code missing:

```java
try {
          completableFuture.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Error while doing join()", e);
        }
```

Then I added those lines of code in, and found that it starts to block execution of the main thread while waiting for the `completableFuture` to finish running.

In short, the behaviour of using `CompletableFuture` seems to be the same as what I found for the initial `Runnable` for my purposes.

Comment: It seems as if you want to use [`CompletableFuture`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture). Please let me know if I am right, then I can convert my comment into an actual answer which you can accept in order to close the question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I read about `CompletableFuture` and tried it out, but I'm finding it behaves the same way as my current `Runnable` for my use case. I'll post an update to the description with more info. If you can see that I'm doing something wrong with how I'm using `CompletableFuture`, feel free to point it out to me.

Comment: Thanks, but would you mind just publishing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the problem on GitHub? At the moment, if I want to help you, I have to set up a whole application, guess about your exact configuration, copy and paste your code and might be able to reproduce the problem or not.

Comment: On a second thought, I believe that your question might actually be more of a Kafka than an AOP question. I have no idea about Kafka and if/how this DLQ thingy works in multi-threaded environments. I am just an AOP expert, sorry. what I can tell you about multi-threading is that without special constructs like `CompletableFuture` you have no chance to handle exceptions thrown in another thread. Maybe in your `handle()` block you need to call some Kafka method in order to add something to the DLQ. Maybe it is already too late because the action is considered finished already.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's more of a Kafka issue. The way it works in other places in our codebase is that if an exception is thrown and is not caught, then Kafka considers the message to be a failure and sends it to the DLQ.

The fact that this is being done in an annotation isn't really the issue. We actually have similar code in our codebase that I've based my annotation on, and the goal is to replace it with an annotation so we can reuse it and have less duplicated code. I understand that the non-annotation version of this code also has the issue I've raised here.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A small correction with regard to your use of terminology: You talk about **aspects** and maybe related terms like **joinpoint, pointcut, advice**. The fact that your pointcut targets methods with a certain annotation is just a special case of a pointcut. The **annotation** as such does nothing at all and does not implement anything. It is just what the name implies: an annotations. It just sits there in the code, getting ignored, unless some other piece of code decides to examine it and do something as a consequence of finding it or if it carrying specific parameter information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a last resort, I ended up handling the error inside the `Runnable` by publishing the error manually to the DLQ, rather than relying upon Spring Cloud Stream to handle this for me. The end result works, although it is obviously not an ideal solution.